# Diffusion of perfume according to fick's law

Tags: diffusion, chemical-potential

Fick's first law relates the diffusive flux to the concentration under the assumption of steady state. It postulates that the flux goes from regions of high concentration to regions of low concentration.
Does this mean if we place a perfume in open air (uncoverd) then by time the perfume container will become empty? i.e all the perfume will spread through the air?

Comment: *Does this mean if we place a perfume in open air (uncoverd) then by time the perfume container will become empty? i.e all the perfume will spread through the air?* In essence *no pun intended!)*, YES! But it'll take a mighty long time...

Comment: Will the gravity and inter-molecular forces prevent the diffusion process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diffusion happens because all regions do not have the same concentration. So it will stop when concentration is same everywhere. The perfume container may never become absolutely empty of perfume molecules. Because that would mean absolute zero concentration.

For all practical purposes though given enough time a perfume container will lose enough perfume molecules that it becomes non-fragrant for human senses.

Comment: Will the gravity and inter-molecular forces prevent the diffusion process?

Comment: I think gravitational effect would be too small to have any visible effect on Earth. I can think of at least one case where inter-molecular forces will have an effect. Some perfume molecules will get stuck to the container. These will continue to diffuse to air at very low diffusion rate. That's why a perfume container is fragrant for a long time after it is empty.